# Failed to create virtual environment in PyCharm (Python 3.4 )

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv

I'm working on a project which requires Python 3.4 due to needing old modules which have not been maintained in ten years. For this I'm trying to create a virtual environment in Pycharm, but it's not been working. I'd be super grateful if someone can help me out!!!

I try to create an environment like this (project folders obscured for privacy reasons):
[image: environment creation screen]

Then the result is this error message:
[image: Error message: Failed to create virtual environment]

I have followed suggestions in another thread and this is a dump of my log file:

```
2023-05-28 19:37:12,477 [1924503]   INFO -
#c.j.p.p.PyCondaPackageService - Using D:\Codes\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe as a conda executable (specified as a preferred conda path) 2023-05-28 19:37:12,477 [1924503]   INFO -
#c.j.p.p.PyCondaPackageService - Using D:\Codes\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe as a conda executable (specified as a preferred conda path) 2023-05-28 19:37:12,477 [1924503]   INFO -
#c.j.p.p.PyCondaPackageService - Using D:\Codes\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe as a conda executable for D:/Codes/anaconda3/python.exe (found as a relative to the env) 2023-05-28 19:37:15,915 [1927941]   INFO -
#c.j.p.p.PyPackageManagerImpl - Running packaging tool: D:\Codes\Python3.4.4\python.exe -S D:\Codes\PyCharm Community Edition
2022.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv.pyz D:\-----\Pycharm_Projects\-----\venv 2023-05-28 19:37:16,243 [1928269] INFO - #c.j.p.p.PyPackageManagerImpl - Exit code 1 2023-05-28 19:37:16,243 [1928269]   INFO - #c.j.p.p.PyPackageManagerImpl - Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Codes\Python3.4.4\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)   File "D:\Codes\Python3.4.4\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)   File "D:\Codes\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv.pyz\__main__.py", line 167, in <module>   File "D:\Codes\PyCharm Community Edition
2022.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv.pyz\__main__.py", line 161, in run   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in
_find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible   File "D:\Codes\PyCharm Community Edition
2022.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv.pyz\virtualenv\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible   File "D:\Codes\PyCharm Community Edition
2022.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv.pyz\virtualenv\run\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible   File "D:\Codes\PyCharm Community Edition
2022.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv.pyz\virtualenv\app_data\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>   File "D:\Codes\PyCharm Community Edition
2022.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv.pyz\__virtualenv__/platformdirs-2.4.1-py3-none-any/platformdirs/__init__.py", line 29
    result: type[PlatformDirsABC] = getattr(importlib.import_module(module), name)
          ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

2023-05-28 19:37:17,035 [1929061]   INFO - #c.i.u.EnvironmentUtil - shell environment loaded (56 vars) 2023-05-28 19:37:19,121 [1931147]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appFileTypeManager took 15 ms
```

From what I can tell, there are any number of issues that could cause this. I have no clue which one, and if it is related to Python 3.4 specifically or my PyCharm installation or what. If anyone can help, thank you so much! I'm stuck and can't continue this project as is!!!

Comment: I believe that maybe the `virtualenv` module's code isn't compatible with python 3.4, at least this default version.
I guess the default python in your system is more advanced than 3.4, so download python 3.4 explicitly and install `virtualenv` with it, that should guarantee a `virtualenv` version that is compatible with python 3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a bunch of things, the solution was to pip install virtualenv on the base Python 3.4 install and then manually creating the virtual env by terminal command (doable in Pycharm using the base python as interpreter):

```
[Python path]\Python -m venv [Pycharm project path]\venv
```

ALSO IMPORTANT WARNING: Do NOT upgrade pip to the latest version at any point! In Python 3.4 this now completely breaks pip, because the latest version requires the Typing module which is not native to 3.4. Look up what the latest supported version of pip for 3.4 is and upgrade to that and no further. This will save you a bunch of annoyance I had to go through, haha.

(And just obligatory: obviously if at all possible work in the most recent version of Python. Sadly if like me you need to use legacy modules that have not been maintained, this may not be possible and you get to deal with these shenanigans.)